# Mongodb $limit in aggregation changes sorting order

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have two queries for aggregation, the only one difference is $limit (in first case it`s 30, second one is 1000000)

Here is the sample

`[{"$match":{...}},{"$sort":{"scan_date":1,"hotel_name":1}},{"$skip":0},{"$limit":1000000}]`

    `[{"$match":{...}},{"$sort":{"scan_date":1,"hotel_name":1}},{"$skip":0},{"$limit":30}]`

The problem is that in results two docs with same "scan_date" and "hotel_name" but different other fields values may be swapped in second query.
For example

First query results:

```
1) hotel_name: a, scan_date: b, some_field c;
2) hotel_name: a, scan_date: b, some_field d;
```

Second query results:

```
1) hotel_name: a, scan_date: b, some_field d;
2) hotel_name: a, scan_date: b, some_field c;
```

Comment: Notably you are not sorting `some_field` here. The common problem is that where the other fields you actually are sorting on contain the same values across the sample, then which ones come out in whatever order are not guaranteed. If you expect a certain order to be maintained, then include a field with "unique" values ( such as `_id` ) at the end of the list of fields to sort.

Comment: @NeilLunn, thanks, it worked for me.